# Moodle with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, moodle

I'm having a tough time integrating moodle with sqlserver through FREEDTS even after reading the documentation in the moodle site.

I've setup the settings in freedts.conf,php.ini and Config.php.

But, inspite of all this it does not connect to my database. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

What could I possibly be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the relevant sections of those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you built PHP with support for FreeTDS as described in the [FreeTDS User Guide](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/php.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it running with SQL Server 2008 and IIS by following the guide from [BFC Networks](http://www.bfcnetworks.com/whitepapers/installing-moodle-2-on-windows-server-2008-r2-x64-sql-iis/). The primary thing was using SQL Server 2.0 for PHP to complete the integration.